# How to make a method forbidden to direct request but allowed for server requests on Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

What I basically want to know is this:

Suppose I have a method annotated with @RequestMapping and the value "/test/ajax". Can I make that specific method accessible only to internal calls but not to the client? If I run an ajax request on that url from within the server it should work normally, but if I run it directly from the browser it should return a 403.

Is that in any way possible?

Answer (score 0):

add the spring annotation @CrossOrigin on controller layer for example
also, follow the given link https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/account")
public class AccountController {


    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Account retrieve(@PathVariable Long id) {
        // ...
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void remove(@PathVariable Long id) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you allow only a method pass like this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/account")
public class AccountController {

    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Account retrieve(@PathVariable Long id) {
        // ...
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void remove(@PathVariable Long id) {
        // ...
    }
}
```